# Adding Environment Variables to Azure Static Web App Release Task

Tags: reactjs, azure, single-page-application, azure-deployment

My react frontend SPA has some environment variables I would like to pass at deploy time using the Static Web App Deploy task in Azure ADO.

If I'm doing this in a pipeline, it's simple to add directly to the YAML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-authentication/static-web-app-with-api/deploy-static-web-app-to-azure#add-react-client-environment-variables-to-workflow-configuration-file

However, within the "Releases", I don't see where I can add these env variables since I can't directly edit the YAML file.

My questions are:

1. Is this not possible? Is this limitation due to the fact the Deploy Static Web App is technically still in "Preview"?
2. Is it possible to write a custom Task/YAML code to run during the release? I would prefer to keep the CD in the Releases section so I can keep approvals/rollback functionality, rather than just make a multi-stage pipeline
3. Is there a better or more correct way to pass these environment variables? They are not secrets, just for example the API URL. Passing as env variables would allow me to break up deployment into dev/prod and pass different values for each environment.

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of Release Task within ADO and inputs]